# How to print several reports with barcode \ or several barcodes in one report

Tags: java, oracle, jasper-reports

I've got a *barcode* report which is using a sequence (*Oracle* backend) to generate my *barcode* numbers.

This is in my query:

```sql
SELECT to_char(PALLET_ID_NO_SEQ.nextval) FROM dual
```

I placed this field in designer window which will display the *barcode* value.

I have an image with expression:

```java
new com.pepkorit.BarbecueRotateRenderer(
    net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeFactory.createCode128C(
    $F{TO_CHAR(PALLET_ID_NO_SEQ.NEXTVAL)}), false, true, 1, 50, 190, 50)
```

The above is the *barcode* using the sequence value.

I want to be able to say to print/generate 100 or more reports. At this moment I'm able to generate only one report at a time.

So my first guess is to get a parameter that prompts the user a value and that value will indicate how many *barcodes* to be printed and each with an individual number.

I'm not sure that my ideas about solving this problem are right and how to do it.

Can someone please help?

Comment: As I understand, there is no way to generate interactive Jasper Reports ( at least for desktop ). So, you need first ask user about the number of desired barcodes and after that generate the report.

Comment: @AndreiPodoprigora Right, so lets say I want to generate 100 reports from the one I already created. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be easily done with small modifying of your query without programming in several ways.

### Solution 1. Using single report with Barcode component in Detail band

You can use single report's template for generating several barcodes in **one** report.

In this case the ***queryString*** expression (works for *Oracle* DB) will be like this:

```sql
SELECT seq_barcode.nextval AS barcode, rownum FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= $P{quantity}
```

- it is generates a value from the sequence as many times as you need. The ***$P{quantity}*** parameter determines the number of rows (barcodes) to be generated.

The working *rjxml* file:

```xml
<jasperReport ...>
    <parameter name="quantity" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[20]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT seq_barcode.nextval AS barcode, rownum FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= $P{quantity}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="BARCODE" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="ROWNUM" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <title>
        <band height="82" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="145" y="18" width="240" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["The number of barcodes is: " + $P{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="47" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="145" y="10" width="200" height="28"/>
                <jr:barbecue xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" type="2of7" drawText="false" checksumRequired="false">
                    <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$F{BARCODE}]]></jr:codeExpression>
                </jr:barbecue>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be (***$P{quantity} == 5***):

[image: The result via preview in iReport]

---

In your case the ***queryString*** expression will be like this:

```sql
SELECT to_char(PALLET_ID_NO_SEQ.nextval) AS barcode, rownum FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= $P{quantity}
```

and the expression of *Barcode* component will be:

```java
new com.pepkorit.BarbecueRotateRenderer(
    net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeFactory.createCode128C($F{barcode}),
    false, true, 1, 50, 190, 50)
```

### Solution 2. Using Group Header band

You can use the same ***queryString*** expression as in the first solution. The group on ***rownum*** field will help us to generate **single** report with many barcodes belonging to its own group (one group - one barcode). The *Barcode* component should be placed to the *Group Header* band.

Using the ***isStartNewPage*** property we can manage to generate group on new page or not.

The *rjxml* file:

```xml
<jasperReport ...>
    <parameter name="quantity" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[20]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT seq_barcode.nextval AS barcode, rownum FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= $P{quantity}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="BARCODE" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="ROWNUM" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <group name="rownumGroup" isStartNewPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ROWNUM}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <componentElement>
                    <reportElement x="145" y="11" width="200" height="28"/>
                    <jr:barbecue xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" type="2of7" drawText="false" checksumRequired="false">
                        <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$F{BARCODE}]]></jr:codeExpression>
                    </jr:barbecue>
                </componentElement>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <title>
        <band height="82" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="145" y="18" width="240" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["The number of barcodes is: " + $P{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

In case ***isStartNewPage="false"*** for group **rownumGroup** the result will be (***$P{quantity}== 7***):

[image: The result via preview in iReport, isStartNewPage="false"]

In case ***isStartNewPage="true"*** for group **rownumGroup** the result will be (***$P{quantity} == 5***):

[image: The result via preview in iReport, isStartNewPage="true"]

### Solution 3. Using subreport

We can add *Subreport* component to the *Detail* band (*see first solution*) or *Group Header* (*see second solution*) band. In this case you can add to the subreport not only the *Barcode* component, but everything you want.

Comment: What is the reason of downvote? It is a working, tested sample.

Comment: @wernervdh8 I've just add several other solutions

Comment: Maybe the length of the answer combined with that opening line "It can be easily done"?  I voted you up.

Comment: @JasonSperske It is not a Trojan Horse ))

Comment: @AlexK Thanks Alex. Looks really promising. I will test it asap and let you know what the outcome is

Comment: Thank Alex. Your post helped me big time

Answer (score 0):

One possible way :

1) Create a bean :

```
public class Entity {
    private Image image;

    public Entity(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Entity() {}

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

2) Populate 100 of such beans with data ( image of your barcode )

3) Create a jasper report like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ExtendedPortReport" language="groovy" pageWidth="1190" pageHeight="842" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="1150" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="0.75"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="image" class="java.awt.Image"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="750" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="RetainShape" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Top" isUsingCache="true" onErrorType="Blank">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="1150" height="750"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </box>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{image}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

4) Set type of image field ( in the report ) to java.awt.Image

5) Create the report as a desktop application ( in your case, use other ways, if needed )

```
    final JasperReport report = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(MAIN_BINARY_PATH);
    final JRDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(/*there is your list of entities*/);

    final JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, dataSource);
    JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(jasperPrint);
    //add viewer to a frame/panel
```