# SQL - between , AND

Tags: sql

```
with bar_no as (
select 1 start_bar, 5 end_bar from dual)
select barcode
from (select level barcode
from dual
connect by level <= (select max(end_bar) from bar_no)) a
where exists (
select 1
from bar_no
where barcode between bar_no.start_bar and bar_no.end_bar)
```

This wil retun:
1
2
3
4
5

I need some help to advance this query. How can I set the query to print every number(return) multiple time.

For example:

Print numbers between 1 and 5 AND print every number 3 times.

End result:
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
5

btw. I will use this in Jasper ireport and dont want to use procs , function etc

Please help! thanks in advance

Comment: you can join this query with another `..connect by level<=3` query. that way you can triple each row count.

Comment: @SnowBlind Do you mind showing me an example please?

Comment: Check @Gordon's answer, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the sequences in the `with` statement and then join them together:

```
with bar_no as (
      select 1 start_bar, 5 end_bar from dual
     ),
     codes as (
      select level + start_bar - 1 start_bar
      from bar_no
           connect by level <= end_bar - start_bar + 1
     ),
     counts as (
       select level as repcnt
       from dual connect by level <= 3
     )
select *
from codes cross join counts
order by 1, 2;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! You were fast with the answer! and it was exactly what I wanted! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use corss join as Below

```
with bar_no as (
select 1 start_bar, 5 end_bar from dual)
select barcode
from (select level barcode
from dual
connect by level <= (select max(end_bar) from bar_no)) a
where exists (
select 1
from bar_no
cross join 
(
  select 1
  union all
  select 2
  union all
  select 3  
   ) CJ
where barcode between bar_no.start_bar and bar_no.end_bar)
```