# Design page according to sticker in jasper report version 6.1

Tags: jasper-reports, barcode

I wanted to design page so that it can print according to my need.
Below is the sample format where i am going to put the the information.
[image: Sample Sticker]

After filling information from jasper it should look something like this.

[image: After printing details]

Height of the sticker is 1.5 mm and width is 6.5 mm.(Converted MM to Pixel)

Can someone confirm is it possible to print something so small using jasper tool or I need to use another tool for the same.
AFAIK this can not be done using jasper but need some expert's opinion or he/she might help me achieve this.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.0.final using 
      JasperReports Library version 6.1.0  -->
          <!-- 2017-06-23T15:17:43 -->
           <jasperReport 
      xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports 
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="EyesDeal" 
pageWidth="19" pageHeight="6" columnWidth="19" leftMargin="0" 
rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="fb138a88-3df3-448f-
a088-5fd7264c303f">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="demo
 "/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM JS]]>
</queryString>
<field name="COL1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="COL2" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="COL3" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="COL4" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="COL5" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="COL6" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="COL7" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="COL8" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="COL9" class="java.lang.String"/>
<detail>
    <band height="5" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="-1" width="18" height="6" uuid="5928e256-73fd-408d-8ba2-e566f4ddaa08">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box topPadding="2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font fontName="Serif" size="2"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: Great so can you guide me !!

Comment: You can look at [How to print several reports with barcode \ or several barcodes in one report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12490881/876298) post

Comment: Thanks for the hint i need to ask you i have a barcode on my page i want to print every barcode on new page is it possible to do so

Comment: Yes. You can use page break, for example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print several reports with barcode \ or several barcodes in one report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490881/how-to-print-several-reports-with-barcode-or-several-barcodes-in-one-report)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link :
[How to print several reports with barcode \ or several barcodes in one report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490881/how-to-print-several-reports-with-barcode-or-several-barcodes-in-one-report)

And when it comes to page break follow below steps:
1) Take rownum in select statement.
2) Create Group based on rownum and check open new page checkbox.

So every time rownum changes it will generate new page.